# Second stylesheet in child template / Overriding style sheets

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates

I have a website i'm putting together with python and django.
I have a template html page, `Speakers.html`, that extends `Base.html`. `Base.html` has the stylesheet `base.css`.

`Speakers.html` is displaying with `base.css` styling as it should be, my problem  is that I want `Speakers.html` to have additional styling from another stylesheet, `speakers.css`.

I've been trying to figure it out but `speaker.css` doesn't seem to be applied, *infact i've just noticed in the cmd output that the file speaker.css isn't being loaded at all.*

I tried putting it in a block, which is the code you now see below.. I had to repeat `{% load static %}` to get rid of an error about it expecting the endblock but it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

**Base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Base.Html</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="{% static "CSS/base.css" %}" />
    {% block additionalcss %}{% endblock %}
</head>

<body>

...ect
```

**Speakers.html**

```
<!-- extending works -->
{% extends "Base.html" %} 


 <!-- Now i'm trying to load an additional stylesheet -->
{% block additionalcss %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="{% static "CSS/speakers.css" %}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block currentpage_content %}
<h2>Guest speakers at the event</h2>

<p> This text would be red if speakers.css was applying properly </p>
...ect
```

For testing purposes i've put the following rule in speakers.css:

```
*
{
color: red;
}
```

So I reason the text on Speakers.html should all be red if it were working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `blocks` in the templates.

Something like:

**Base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Base.Html</title>
    {% load static %}

    {% block css %}{% endblock %}
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="{% static "CSS/base.css" %}" />
</head>

<body>

...ect
```

**Speakers.html**

```
<!-- extending works -->
{% extends "Base.html" %} 

{% block css %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="{% static "CSS/speakers.css" %}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block currentpage_content %}
<h2>Guest speakers at the event</h2>

<p> This text would be red if speakers.css was applying properly </p>
...ect
```

By defining blocks in the parents and then specifying them in the children the css files will be inserted into your template.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse! I did try that but it doesn't seem to work, first i got an error, cant remember it exactly but it was something about it not liking the use of {% static ".." %} because it's expecting the endblock . So i tried adding in {% load static %} again before the <link> and it compiled fine but still isnt applying the css. I also noticed in the cmd output that speakers.css does not appear to be being loaded whatsoever.

Comment: strike that. Bizarrely this solution is working fine this morning, the only conclusion I can come to is that it was my web browser acting up. Cheers.

Comment: Great. Glad it's worked out for you. :-) You were right about the `static` declaration (I cut it out by mistake). I've edited my answer to correct that.